# Capturing data written to a Node.js socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

The `'data'` event from `net.Socket` can be used to read data received from a socket, for example:

```js
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (buffer)=>{
    console.log(`Server received ${buffer}`)
    socket.write('World');
  });
});
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.on('data', (buffer) => {
  console.log(`Client received ${buffer}`)
});
socket.connect(8080, '127.0.0.1');

setTimeout(()=>{
  socket.write('Hello');
},100);
setTimeout(()=>{
  socket.write('Hi');
},200);

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('Goodbye.');
  socket.destroy();
  server.close();
},300);
```

Prints:

```bash
Server received Hello
Client received World
Server received Hi
Client received World
Goodbye.
```

Is there a way read data *sent out* from a socket? For example if `server` was a remote server, is there a way to capture the data sent to the server from the socket using events or any another method?

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation and reviewing the documentation, I've reached the following understanding:

The information sent to the server through a socket can't be captured directly on the client using events or another approach. The `Socket` class, part of the `net` library in Node.js, **mainly provides ways to send data to the server, and lacks a built-in mechanism to capture the data sent**.

However, *if you have control over the code base of the server*, you can improve the tracking of data. One practical approach is to modify the server's code to log the data it receives from clients. For example, by inserting a logging instruction into an appropriate event handler on the server, you can log the data coming in from clients.

***To sum it up, while directly capturing sent data on the client side isn't currently viable, modifying the server code can allow you to track and log data as it arrives from clients.***

[NodeJS's Net Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#new-netsocketoptions)

Answer (score 1):

if you're looking for a quick-and-dirty way to see what you're sending from the client socket, just wrap `socket.write` like this:

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (buffer)=>{
    socket.write('World');
  });
});

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

const socket = new net.Socket();

const origWrite = socket.write;
socket.write = function(data, enc, cb) {
  // Doing stuff here, like logging or whatever
  origWrite.call(this, data, enc, cb);
};

socket.on('data', (buffer) => {
});

socket.connect(8080, '127.0.0.1');

setTimeout(()=>{
  socket.write('Hello');
},100);

setTimeout(()=>{
  socket.write('Hi');
},200);

setTimeout(()=>{
  socket.destroy();
  server.close();
},300);
```